# Explanation of how one can search youtube.com/music

Tags: youtube, search

Currently the youtube.com/music page looks like

[image]

But these are the same artists over and over again.

[Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWAGLkyxQG0)
*Name*: Wiz Khalifa - Black And Yellow [G-Mix] ft. Snoop Dogg, Juicy J & T-Pain
*Date of YouTube Video release* : January 07, 2011

Sure maybe this guy is popular ever single day but if it updated every two hours shouldn't other videos appear ? (smaller views but relatively high velocity [bowerypresents](http://www.youtube.com/user/bowerypresents) is an example yes but it seems they are a partner])

The graph for the video statistics show almost flat line characteristics with the biggest referral from YouTube/music with 397,704 views.

Ignoring this, if I were to click the Play all button, there are only **8** videos as Today's Hits. What if I wanted the top 10/20 hits ?

---

Moving to a genre... a similar issue occurs,

it is not Genres, but Popular Genres. Alright so the categories are at the top.
Let us try reggae http://www.youtube.com/music/reggae

Check the second video

Shaggy - Angel ft. Rayvon (C) 2001

But apparently it is Today's Top hit in reggae.
Also notice the threshold for # of videos in top hits per genre are **12**. 
So basically whatever can be displayed in the layout on the main music page are the only videos listed. 8 for Today's Hits and 12 for each genre due to the layout.

---

Let us say you wanted to play a genre of music for example Pop/Rock

(Which has now changed finally while writing this question/desc. but still only holds popular artists)

[image]

If I were to click Play Pop/Rock, I end up with a [Mike Posner Mix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqWq_48LxWQ&feature=artist&playnext=1&list=MLGxdCwVVULXe_bxdGmo2J9Kl8f_GtxMgZ) of 36 videos including [Wiz Khalifa - Youngin On His Grind](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5amgjY18SCM) which is somehow Pop/Rock ...

In the previous setup of the music page, I was pretty sure there were alot more ways to traverse artists and even check up on rising ones too.

---

**Can someone please explain what is going on in the /music section** so I can understand how to use it properly ?

I thought maybe there was a next way to do search so I started checking out [Google Music](http://www.google.com/landing/music/) and well that got nowhere since it is still in the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since youTube changed the music section and it is now pretty much useless.

The nearest thing to what you want would be http://www.youtube.com/charts

You can then filter this by music and the most viewed, most popular etc.  The problem with this is that you can't filter by genre.

All in all the changes made to the music section totally suck.